# passing user roles to site inside iframe in a liferay portlet

Tags: iframe, liferay

I am adding an iFrame to the page in Liferay which points to an external webapp.  In order to function properly, this webapp needs to have the roles of the user who is logged in to Liferay and using the portlet.

[From this documentation.](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Iframe+Portlet#section-Iframe+Portlet-Basic+vs+form+based+authentication)

I know how to pass the user_id and screen name to the external webapp, but not the roles.  I know I can probably look them up in the liferay db with the user_id, but is there a way to pass the roles somehow through iFrame? Maybe in hidden variables?

Thank you.

Comment: is the external webapp on the same server? then you can make it with cookies.

Answer (score 1):

You can write jsp hook to override html/portlet/iframe/proxy.jsp. And add your user role as hidden parameter.